# Nautilus won't launch on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, nautilus

I know there are other threads about this. I tried them but the offered solutions did not work and I'm not allowed to comment on the thread to ask for clarification, yet.

The only thing I've changed recently is the settings on my Numix icon theme (from default to green folders). This is the response I get when attempting to launch Nautilus from terminal:

```
************:~$ nautilus

(nautilus:23691): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:23691): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
Could not register the application: Timeout was reached

(nautilus:23691): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(nautilus:23691): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(nautilus:23691): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

Comment: "I know there are other threads about this. I tried them but the offered solutions did not work and I'm not allowed to comment on the thread to ask for clarification, yet." Please improve your question and link to these; or describe what you have tried and what the results were. As for now your question may cause reactions like "I have an idea but nah... he has probably tried that" which may not be true. If you write something like "I tried this solution (link) but the output was... and I need clarification with...", then maybe you will get clarification here.

Answer (score 2):

Seems related to [this *fix released* bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1569970). Some people say just a full upgrade (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`) and reboot (`systemctl reboot`) solve it. but for me at least temporary was:

```
killall nautilus && setsid nautilus
```

From [killall](https://linux.die.net/man/1/killall) and [setsid](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setsid) man pages:

> **killall** - kill processes by name
>
> **setsid** - run a program in a new session